# WordPress: Plugin not send emails on Hotmail.

Tags: php, wordpress, email, contact-form-7

I've developed a WordPress theme and included plugin named as contact-form-7.

how ever it works perfectly and sends emails with gmail and other email service providers but not to Hotmail.

Hotmail servers let that as spam and Hotmail not receiving emails by that plugin.

What i tried so far,
-> tried to change headers many times
-> searched on Google many times for this plugin issue solution but didn't helped
-> tried to put valid email address in "From" field of the form (plugin)

have anybody used this plugin ? actually I'm using this thing first time.

please help, I'm badly stuck with it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check your spam folder?

Comment: yes, i found the problem, it is hotmail side problem. hotmail keep letting this as spam and not sending it to email account.

it gets email for only first time , then after all messages it lets as spam and hotmail not allowing it to email account.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention what mechanism you are using to send mail. And it's not clear what is happening to your email, you mention both 'not being received' and 'spam' and it can't be both.

I am willing to bet if you use an [OAuth 2.0 SMTP plugin to send Hotmail](https://wordpress.org/plugins/postman-smtp/) your messages will stop disappearing. This requires a (free) Microsoft OAuth 2.0 Client ID.

Comment: It was problem at hotmail, not at the code, thanks for help by the way.